# Modify and Access Class Variables in Python

Tags: python

I have a method in my python code, which utilizes recursion. Essentially, I need a variable, which doesn't get erased each time it recursive. I need a class variable outside the method, in which the method can use and modify. This is my code so far:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s %3 == 0 and s!=0:
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    max = 0;

    subset_sum([10,9,8,7,6,5,8,9,7],10000000)
    print max
    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

I tried doing something like this to make the class variable:

```
  max = 0;
  def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s %3 == 0 and s!=0:
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if max<s:
            max = s
            print max
            print s
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    max = 0;

    subset_sum([10,9,8,7,6,5,8,9,7],10000000)
    print max
    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

I said max = s, but I am getting tons of errors:

```html
sum([10, 9, 8])=10000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    subset_sum([10,9,8,7,6,5,8,9,7],10000000)
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 18, in subset_sum
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 18, in subset_sum
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 18, in subset_sum
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 9, in subset_sum
    if max<s:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max' referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing Wrong?

-UPDATE

```
  global max
  def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s %3 == 0 and s!=0:
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if max<s:
            max = s
            print "hi"
        print max
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    max = 0;

    subset_sum([10,9,8,7,6,5,8,9,7],10000000)
    print max
    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

The error is the same as previous:

```
  File "C:/Users/BOB/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 9, in subset_sum
    if max<s:
  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the recursive call `subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])` - whatever the return value is (if any) just gets thrown away, so your overall function is likely to return `None` in most cases. I assume you want to either `return` the result of the recursive call, or (probably more likely with the loop) keep a running total of these results. It's hard for me to be specific as I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want this function to do (in particular the `s%3==0` condition doesn't seem to relate to much else).

Comment: Hi Robin, yeah I realized I changed my question. Please take a look.

Comment: I still don't understand what the code is doing, but to eliminate that error you just need to put `global max` at the start of the function

Comment: Thanks, Robin, I tried what you said regarding global max, however, the error remains the same. I updated the question

Comment: @JohnSmith: `global max` needs to go *inside* the function, not outside it.

Comment: I know im asking a lot of questions, but how do you convert an int array into one int. For example if the array is [1,2,3] then the int should be 123, in python 2.6

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have a new problem which I asked in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583246/after-formatting-python-code-errors-arise