# After formatting Python Code, Errors arise

Tags: python

I wrote a python code, which works correctly with no errors:

```
  def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    global max
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s%3 == 0:
       # print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if s != 0:
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in partial)
            y = int(str1)
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in max)
            z = int(str1)
            if y>z:
                max = partial

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    max = [0, 0, 0, 0,0];

    subset_sum([3,1,4,1,5,9],15)
    max =  sorted(max, key=int, reverse=True)
    print max
    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

I reformated my code a bit:

```
  def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    print "hi"
    global max
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s%3 == 0:
       # print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if s != 0:
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in partial)
            y = int(str1)
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in max)
            z = int(str1)
            if y>z:
                max = partial

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

  def answer(l):

    max = [0, 0, 0, 0,0];
    subset_sum(l,15)
    max =  sorted(max, key=int, reverse=True)
    return max

  answer([3,1,4,1,5,9])
```

Essentially I just add another function, which calls upon subset_sum.
However, I am getting errors in my new formated the code:

```html
  hi
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  hi
    File "C:/Users/Bob/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 33, in <module>
      answer([3,1,4,1,5,9])
    File "C:/Users/Bob/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 29, in answer
      subset_sum(l,15)
    File "C:/Users/Bob/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 24, in subset_sum
      subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
    File "C:/Users/Bob/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 13, in subset_sum
      str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in max)
  TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

What is wrong with my formatted code? Just to clarify my original code works perfect, my original code is the first code snippet. Then the second code snippet is the formated code, however that gives me errors. I showed my error. I do not know why I am getting errors, please help.

--UPDATED CODE--

```
  maximum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):

    global maximum
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s%3 == 0:
       # print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if s != 0:
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in partial)
            y = int(str1)
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in maximum)
            z = int(str1)
            if y>z:
                maximum = partial
                print maximum

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

  def answer(l):
    maximum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    subset_sum(l,15)
    maximum =  sorted(maximum, key=int, reverse=True)
    return maximum

  print(answer([3,1,4,1,5,9]))
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the name `max` as a variable.

Comment: Notice `max` isn't defined if a certain conditional is not executed. And if you don't define `max`, since you're shadowing a built-in Python function name, Python will attempt to use the builtin `max` function in the expression `str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in max)`, which obviously won't work. Firstly, make sure variables aren't just defined in conditionals. Always define variables outside of conditionals. Secondly, don't shadow builtin variable names. Use some other name rather than `max`.

Comment: What is `max` in the global scope? It seems it hasn't been assigned to anything yet, so it is the built-in `max` function in Python. It is typically considered bad Python practice to give variables the same names as built-in functions (such as `max`)

Comment: Note: Setting `max` to a value in a function will not touch the `max` in global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, a note: don't use `max` as a variable name; it is a built-in function which returns the item in a list with the highest value.*

In your `subset_sum()` function, you have the line

```
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in max)
```

Which tries to iterate (loop) through the predefined function, as there is no redefinition of `max` before you use it (variables need to be created/defined/initalised before you use them).

Sure, you do have `global max` at the beginning of the function, but because there is no variables called `max` outside of the function, it defaults to using the built-in function.

---

Fixed code (note the usage of `_max` rather than `maximum`):

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):

    global _max
    s = sum(partial)


    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s%3 == 0:
       # print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
        if s != 0:
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in partial)
            y = int(str1)
            str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in _max)
            z = int(str1)
            if y>z:
                _max = partial

    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

def answer(l):
    global _max
    subset_sum(l,15)
    _max =  sorted(_max, key=int, reverse=True)
    return _max

_max = [0, 0, 0, 0,0];
answer([3,1,4,1,5,9])
```

Comment: But i said max = [0, 0, 0, 0,0]; In the answer function. Will that not work?

Comment: No, because `max = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` is local to `answer()`, meaning that the redefinition is only limited to code within that function.

Comment: How would I fix it?

Comment: First of all, don't use `max` as a variable name. Second of all, place `max = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` outside of any functions.

Comment: Okay, I updated my code in the question. I changed max to maximum. However, when I print the final maximum (print(answer([3,1,4,1,5,9]))) it returns [0,0,0,0,0]. Essentially it changes maximum. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I do modify maximum: (maximum = partial) in the subset_sum function. Within that function, I also print out maximum to test if it changed. It is printing the correct values when i am in that function. However when I return it from the answer function I get a different maximum